# MongoDB - Partial update of document and no model class

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to do generic updates-partial of mongo documents without using model class. I tried reading through and follow many examples- but unfortunately no luck. I am using `MongoTemplate` and mongo Java driver 4.2.
Have anyone done this when mongo document has embedded documents ?

Here is one of the trials i am doing.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/update")

       public UpdateResult update(@RequestBody String json, String key,String collection, String value) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

              System.out.println("inside update" + key+ "value" + value);

             Document query = new Document(key, value);

             Document mongo = Document.parse(json);

             // Update field by field, instead of replacing the whole object to preserve existing fields like "_lock"

               List<Bson> updates = new ArrayList<>(mongo.size());

               mongo.forEach((s, o) -> {

                 updates.add(new Document("$set", new Document(s, o)));

               });
        

                 UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();

              

                 options.upsert(true);

            

                    MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection);

               return coll.updateOne(query,

                             Updates.combine(updates), options);
       }
```

However - when i pass these samples - the elements still get removed

sample Jsons

```
{ 

     "id" : "XWZ7890", 

    "Attributes" : {

        "Food" : {

            "Fruits" : "8000",

             "Vegetables" : "600",

            "Chicken" : "578"

            }

    }

}
```

The above one adds document to mongo.

Now if i send a partial json - with only one attribute - the db removes all attributes which was not in the json.

```
{ 

     "id" : "XWZ7890", 

    "Attributes" : {

        "Food" : {

            "Fruits" : "7000"

            }

    }

}
```

Please help in providing suggestions..

Comment: Do any of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+update+field+in+embedded+document

Comment: please add your requirement with relevant example and what you tried

Comment: as in the examples above - i tried to use set operator, and also tried to use dot annotation. but most of the examples here are using hardcoded elements in the document.  Ideally i want a generic implementation-so i tried to iterate through the json-using keys - tried to identify non null keys- and then tried to update using set when value is non null for any keys. didnt succeed though and got stuck on arrays.

Comment: Set Operator sets the value of the provided key. Here you are passing Attributes as key and nested json as value, so it will set the whole Attributes object. If you want to set only single property then you need to set "Attributes.Food.Fruits"

Comment: yes- wondering how to do it generically without model class.. i dont know what attrubute will change for each transaction. sometimes Fruits/sometimes vegetables... and the document can have more keys as well. Trying to identify keys with change...